# To create a comma separated equation in python

Tags: python, for-loop

how to create an undefined number equation. Lets suppose if we did not know the the value of n , then how to generate a1 , a2 , a3 ,an.

```
if n= 5 

a1 , a2 , a3 , a4 , a5 = 5
```

Comment: Use a list/array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Numby package to solve a undefined number equation:

```
import numpy as np
 
a = np.array([[3,1], [1,2]])
b = np.array([9,8])
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
print(x)
```